# How to parallax headlines with Stellar.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, parallax

I have a few elements and I am using `Stellar.JS` to make elements slide while scrolling - Parallax.

Here is the example:[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hCKG9/)

I would like headline `Trainers` to go UP while scrolling. I've used `data-stellar-ratio="2"` on it, but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your fiddle is not correctly set up. You can't link a github ressource (go to http://cdnjs.com/ to find linkable ressources), and you didn't select jquery framework. Here's a corrected one :
http://jsfiddle.net/hCKG9/1/

Moreover, to make elements "parallaxed" with Stellar.js, you must give them a position, like `position:absolute` (or relative, or fixed)